# Fourier transform definition on $L^2$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

I'm trying to prove that $C^\infty_0(R^n)$ as the set of those smooth functions with compact support, is included in the set $X=\{f\in L^1(R^n) \ : \ \hat{f}\in L^1(R^n)\}$.

All because our professor said that one could define the Fourier transform on $L^2(R^n)$ by density of $X$ in $L^2$ and he claimed that this is a consequence of the density of $C^\infty_0$ in $L^2$ and of the inclusion $C^\infty_0\subseteq X\subseteq L^2$. Of course, $X\subset L^2$, but I can't see how $C^\infty_0\subset X$, since I only know that if $f\in C^\infty_0$, then $\hat{f}\in C^\infty\cap C_0$ (where $C_0$ is the set of all continuous functions which goes to 0 as $|x|\rightarrow+\infty$).

I tried to comb through some text, but I only saw authors using the density of $L^1\cap L^2$ in $L^2$ to define the Fourier transform on $L^2$...

Comment: A smooth function with compact support is in particular a Schwartz function. Do you know that the Fourier transform of a Schwartz function is Schwartz? If so, this is all what you need, since the Schwartz space is obviously contained in $L^1$.

Comment: I know Fourier transform maps Schwartz's space in itself isomorphically, but I hoped there was another explanation to the inclusion, simply because we treated Schwartz's space after Fourier transform in $L^2$ (otherwise, it would have been easier to define Fourier transform on $L^2$ directly from Schwartz's space).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could show that for $f\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$, $\lvert\hat{f}(\xi)\rvert=O(\lvert\xi\rvert^{-1})$ as $\lvert\xi\rvert\to\infty$, and similarly for $C^1_c(\mathbb{R})$ you then get $O(\lvert\xi\rvert^{-2})$.  This gives $\hat{f}\in L^1$.

Of course you would recognize it as part of the proof of Fourier transform of Schwartz is Schwartz, adapted to our case.